# Error installing the stringi package on R 4 on Linux Ubuntu

Tags: r, roxygen2, stringi

I'm trying to install the [roxygen2](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/roxygen2/index.html) package on R 4.0.3 on Linux Ubuntu 16.04.7 LTS. It fails because it needs the [stringi](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/stringi/) package to be installed first; I try to install it with the usual command `install.packages("stringi")` but it fails again and I cannot understand why.
Here's the log:

> install.packages("stringi") Installing package into
> ‘/home/dave/R/x86_64-conda-linux-gnu-library/4.0’ (as ‘lib’ is
> unspecified)
> --- Please select a CRAN mirror for use in this session --- trying URL 'https://ftp.eenet.ee/pub/cran/src/contrib/stringi_1.5.3.tar.gz'
> Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 7293930 bytes (7.0 MB)
> ================================================== downloaded 7.0 MB
>
> installing *source* package ‘stringi’ ...
> ** package ‘stringi’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
> ** using staged installation checking for R_HOME... /home/dave/miniconda3/envs/r4-base/lib/R checking for R...
> /home/dave/miniconda3/envs/r4-base/lib/R/bin/R checking for
> endianness... little checking for R >= 3.1.0 for C++11 use... yes
> checking for R < 3.4.0 for CXX1X flag use... no checking for cat...
> /bin/cat checking for local ICUDT_DIR... icu61/data checking for
> x86_64-conda-linux-gnu-gcc... x86_64-conda-linux-gnu-cc checking
> whether the C compiler works... yes checking for C compiler default
> output file name... a.out checking for suffix of executables...
> checking whether we are cross compiling... no checking for suffix of
> object files... o checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler...
> yes checking whether x86_64-conda-linux-gnu-cc accepts -g... yes
> checking for x86_64-conda-linux-gnu-cc option to accept ISO C89...
> none needed checking how to run the C preprocessor...
> /home/dave/miniconda3/envs/r4-base/bin/x86_64-conda-linux-gnu-cpp
> checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /bin/grep checking
> for egrep... /bin/grep -E checking for ANSI C header files... yes
> checking for sys/types.h... yes checking for sys/stat.h... yes
> checking for stdlib.h... yes checking for string.h... yes checking for
> memory.h... yes checking for strings.h... yes checking for
> inttypes.h... yes checking for stdint.h... yes checking for
> unistd.h... yes checking elf.h usability... yes checking elf.h
> presence... yes checking for elf.h... yes checking whether we are
> using the GNU C++ compiler... yes checking whether
> x86_64-conda-linux-gnu-c++ -std=gnu++11 accepts -g... yes checking
> whether the C++ compiler supports the long long type... yes checking
> whether the compiler implements namespaces... yes checking whether the
> compiler supports Standard Template Library... yes checking whether
> std::map is available... yes checking for pkg-config...
> /usr/bin/pkg-config checking with pkg-config for the system ICU4C...
> 55.1 checking for ICU4C >= 55... yes checking for additional required CPPFLAGS, LDFLAGS, and LIBS... done checking whether we may build an
> ICU4C-based project... yes checking programmatically for sufficient
> U_ICU_VERSION_MAJOR_NUM... yes checking programmatically if
> U_CHARSET_IS_UTF8 is defined and set... no checking for available ICU
> data library (ucnv, uloc, utrans)... yes checking for available ICU
> data library (ucol)... yes configure: creating ./config.status
> config.status: creating src/Makevars config.status: creating
> src/uconfig_local.h config.status: creating src/install.libs.R
>
> *** stringi configure summary:
> ICU_FOUND=1
> STRINGI_CXXSTD=CXX_STD=CXX11
> STRINGI_CFLAGS=   -fpic
> STRINGI_CPPFLAGS=-I. -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu   -UDEBUG -DNDEBUG -DU_HAVE_ELF_H
> STRINGI_CXXFLAGS=   -fpic
> STRINGI_LDFLAGS=-L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
> STRINGI_LIBS=-licui18n -licuuc -licudata
>
> *** compiler settings used:
> CC=x86_64-conda-linux-gnu-cc
> LD=x86_64-conda-linux-gnu-c++ -std=gnu++11
> CFLAGS=-march=nocona -mtune=haswell -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fstack-protector-strong -fno-plt -O2 -ffunction-sections -pipe -isystem /home/dave/miniconda3/envs/r4-base/include -fdebug-prefix-map=/home/conda/feedstock_root/build_artifacts/r-base-split_1608831447945/work=/usr/local/src/conda/r-base-4.0.3
> -fdebug-prefix-map=/home/dave/miniconda3/envs/r4-base=/usr/local/src/conda-prefix
> -fpic
> CPPFLAGS=-DNDEBUG -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -O2 -isystem /home/dave/miniconda3/envs/r4-base/include
> -I/home/dave/miniconda3/envs/r4-base/include -Wl,-rpath-link,/home/dave/miniconda3/envs/r4-base/lib   -UDEBUG -DNDEBUG
> CXX=x86_64-conda-linux-gnu-c++ -std=gnu++11
> CXXFLAGS=-fvisibility-inlines-hidden -fmessage-length=0 -march=nocona -mtune=haswell -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fstack-protector-strong -fno-plt -O2 -ffunction-sections -pipe -isystem /home/dave/miniconda3/envs/r4-base/include -fdebug-prefix-map=/home/conda/feedstock_root/build_artifacts/r-base-split_1608831447945/work=/usr/local/src/conda/r-base-4.0.3
> -fdebug-prefix-map=/home/dave/miniconda3/envs/r4-base=/usr/local/src/conda-prefix
> -fpic
> LDFLAGS=
> LIBS=
>
> ** libs x86_64-conda-linux-gnu-c++ -std=gnu++11 -I"/home/dave/miniconda3/envs/r4-base/lib/R/include" -DNDEBUG -I. -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu   -UDEBUG -DNDEBUG -DU_HAVE_ELF_H  -DNDEBUG -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -O2 -isystem /home/dave/miniconda3/envs/r4-base/include
> -I/home/dave/miniconda3/envs/r4-base/include -Wl,-rpath-link,/home/dave/miniconda3/envs/r4-base/lib  -fpic -fpic  -fvisibility-inlines-hidden  -fmessage-length=0 -march=nocona -mtune=haswell -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fstack-protector-strong -fno-plt -O2 -ffunction-sections -pipe -isystem /home/dave/miniconda3/envs/r4-base/include
> -fdebug-prefix-map=/home/conda/feedstock_root/build_artifacts/r-base-split_1608831447945/work=/usr/local/src/conda/r-base-4.0.3
> -fdebug-prefix-map=/home/dave/miniconda3/envs/r4-base=/usr/local/src/conda-prefix
> -c stri_brkiter.cpp -o stri_brkiter.o In file included from /home/dave/miniconda3/envs/r4-base/x86_64-conda-linux-gnu/sysroot/usr/include/math.h:71,
> from /home/dave/miniconda3/envs/r4-base/x86_64-conda-linux-gnu/include/c++/9.3.0/cmath:45,
> from /home/dave/miniconda3/envs/r4-base/lib/R/include/R.h:50,
> from stri_external.h:67,
> from stri_stringi.h:36,
> from stri_brkiter.cpp:32: /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/mathcalls.h:63:16: error: expected
> constructor, destructor, or type conversion before '(' token    63 |
> __MATHCALL_VEC (cos,, (*Mdouble* __x));
> |                ^ /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/mathcalls.h:65:16: error: expected
> constructor, destructor, or type conversion before '(' token    65 |
> __MATHCALL_VEC (sin,, (*Mdouble* __x));
> |                ^ /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/mathcalls.h:81:22: error: 'sincos'
> has not been declared    81 | __MATHDECL_VEC (void,sincos,,
> |                      ^~~~~~ /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/mathcalls.h:81:29: error: expected
> identifier before ',' token    81 | __MATHDECL_VEC (void,sincos,,
> |                             ^ /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/mathcalls.h:82:3: error: expected
> identifier before '(' token    82 |   (*Mdouble* __x, *Mdouble*
> *__sinx, *Mdouble* *__cosx));
> |   ^ /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/mathcalls.h:82:57: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before ';'
> token    82 |   (*Mdouble* __x, *Mdouble* *__sinx, *Mdouble*
> *__cosx));
> |                                                         ^ /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/mathcalls.h:100:16: error: expected
> constructor, destructor, or type conversion before '(' token   100 |
> __MATHCALL_VEC (exp,, (*Mdouble* __x));
> |                ^ /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/mathcalls.h:109:16: error: expected
> constructor, destructor, or type conversion before '(' token   109 |
> __MATHCALL_VEC (log,, (*Mdouble* __x));
> |                ^ /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/mathcalls.h:153:16: error: expected
> constructor, destructor, or type conversion before '(' token   153 |
> __MATHCALL_VEC (pow,, (*Mdouble* __x, *Mdouble* __y));
> |                ^ In file included from /home/dave/miniconda3/envs/r4-base/x86_64-conda-linux-gnu/sysroot/usr/include/math.h:94,
> from /home/dave/miniconda3/envs/r4-base/x86_64-conda-linux-gnu/include/c++/9.3.0/cmath:45,
> from /home/dave/miniconda3/envs/r4-base/lib/R/include/R.h:50,
> from stri_external.h:67,
> from stri_stringi.h:36,
> from stri_brkiter.cpp:32: /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/mathcalls.h:63:16: error: expected
> constructor, destructor, or type conversion before '(' token    63 |
> __MATHCALL_VEC (cos,, (*Mdouble* __x));
> |                ^ /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/mathcalls.h:65:16: error: expected
> constructor, destructor, or type conversion before '(' token    65 |
> __MATHCALL_VEC (sin,, (*Mdouble* __x));
> |                ^ /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/mathcalls.h:81:22: error: 'sincos'
> has not been declared    81 | __MATHDECL_VEC (void,sincos,,
> |                      ^~~~~~ /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/mathcalls.h:81:29: error: expected
> identifier before ',' token    81 | __MATHDECL_VEC (void,sincos,,
> |                             ^ /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/mathcalls.h:82:3: error: expected
> identifier before '(' token    82 |   (*Mdouble* __x, *Mdouble*
> *__sinx, *Mdouble* *__cosx));
> |   ^ /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/mathcalls.h:82:57: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before ';'
> token    82 |   (*Mdouble* __x, *Mdouble* *__sinx, *Mdouble*
> *__cosx));
> |                                                         ^ /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/mathcalls.h:100:16: error: expected
> constructor, destructor, or type conversion before '(' token   100 |
> __MATHCALL_VEC (exp,, (*Mdouble* __x));
> |                ^ /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/mathcalls.h:109:16: error: expected
> constructor, destructor, or type conversion before '(' token   109 |
> __MATHCALL_VEC (log,, (*Mdouble* __x));
> |                ^ /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/mathcalls.h:153:16: error: expected
> constructor, destructor, or type conversion before '(' token   153 |
> __MATHCALL_VEC (pow,, (*Mdouble* __x, *Mdouble* __y));
> |                ^ In file included from /home/dave/miniconda3/envs/r4-base/x86_64-conda-linux-gnu/sysroot/usr/include/math.h:141,
> from /home/dave/miniconda3/envs/r4-base/x86_64-conda-linux-gnu/include/c++/9.3.0/cmath:45,
> from /home/dave/miniconda3/envs/r4-base/lib/R/include/R.h:50,
> from stri_external.h:67,
> from stri_stringi.h:36,
> from stri_brkiter.cpp:32: /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/mathcalls.h:63:16: error: expected
> constructor, destructor, or type conversion before '(' token    63 |
> __MATHCALL_VEC (cos,, (*Mdouble* __x));
> |                ^ /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/mathcalls.h:65:16: error: expected
> constructor, destructor, or type conversion before '(' token    65 |
> __MATHCALL_VEC (sin,, (*Mdouble* __x));
> |                ^ /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/mathcalls.h:81:22: error: 'sincos'
> has not been declared    81 | __MATHDECL_VEC (void,sincos,,
> |                      ^~~~~~ /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/mathcalls.h:81:29: error: expected
> identifier before ',' token    81 | __MATHDECL_VEC (void,sincos,,
> |                             ^ /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/mathcalls.h:82:3: error: expected
> identifier before '(' token    82 |   (*Mdouble* __x, *Mdouble*
> *__sinx, *Mdouble* *__cosx));
> |   ^ /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/mathcalls.h:82:57: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before ';'
> token    82 |   (*Mdouble* __x, *Mdouble* *__sinx, *Mdouble*
> *__cosx));
> |                                                         ^ /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/mathcalls.h:100:16: error: expected
> constructor, destructor, or type conversion before '(' token   100 |
> __MATHCALL_VEC (exp,, (*Mdouble* __x));
> |                ^ /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/mathcalls.h:109:16: error: expected
> constructor, destructor, or type conversion before '(' token   109 |
> __MATHCALL_VEC (log,, (*Mdouble* __x));
> |                ^ /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/mathcalls.h:153:16: error: expected
> constructor, destructor, or type conversion before '(' token   153 |
> __MATHCALL_VEC (pow,, (*Mdouble* __x, *Mdouble* __y));
> |                ^ In file included from /home/dave/miniconda3/envs/r4-base/lib/R/include/R.h:50,
> from stri_external.h:67,
> from stri_stringi.h:36,
> from stri_brkiter.cpp:32: /home/dave/miniconda3/envs/r4-base/x86_64-conda-linux-gnu/include/c++/9.3.0/cmath:180:11:
> error: '::cos' has not been declared   180 |   using ::cos;
> |           ^~~ /home/dave/miniconda3/envs/r4-base/x86_64-conda-linux-gnu/include/c++/9.3.0/cmath:218:11:
> error: '::exp' has not been declared   218 |   using ::exp;
> |           ^~~ /home/dave/miniconda3/envs/r4-base/x86_64-conda-linux-gnu/include/c++/9.3.0/cmath:334:11:
> error: '::log' has not been declared   334 |   using ::log;
> |           ^~~ /home/dave/miniconda3/envs/r4-base/x86_64-conda-linux-gnu/include/c++/9.3.0/cmath:384:11:
> error: '::pow' has not been declared   384 |   using ::pow;
> |           ^~~ /home/dave/miniconda3/envs/r4-base/x86_64-conda-linux-gnu/include/c++/9.3.0/cmath:421:11:
> error: '::sin' has not been declared   421 |   using ::sin;
> |           ^~~ make: *** [/home/dave/miniconda3/envs/r4-base/lib/R/etc/Makeconf:181:
> stri_brkiter.o] Error 1 ERROR: compilation failed for package
> ‘stringi’
>
> - removing ‘/home/dave/R/x86_64-conda-linux-gnu-library/4.0/stringi’
>
> The downloaded source packages are in
> ‘/tmp/RtmpkLYZqu/downloaded_packages’ Warning message: In
> install.packages("stringi") :   installation of package ‘stringi’ had
> non-zero exit status

Any idea or suggestion on how to solve this issue?

Thank you

Comment: Is there any more output than that? "Error 1" just means "make stopped because something failed along the way" so it's not too helpful.

Comment: @neilfws I just added the complete log, I hope it can be useful. Thanks

Comment: [This seems to be the same issue](https://github.com/gagolews/stringi/issues/378). The comments there may be helpful.

Comment: That did not help, thanks anyway

Answer (score 4):

I was happily able to solve this issue by myself, by installing `stringi` via [conda](https://anaconda.org/r/r-stringi) :-)

Here's the steps I followed:

1. I updated all the conda packages: `conda update --all`
2. I updated conda: `conda update -n base -c defaults conda`
3. I installed stringi via conda: `conda install -c r r-stringi`

And everything went well! Maybe the step (3) was sufficient by itself, but I wanted to list all the commands I used anyway.

I hope this solution can be useful for someone else too.